# How to get the selected value on the form in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to get the value of the form when the onChange event triggers.  I always get empty string ("");

```
$form = $formFactory->createBuilder()
    ->add('Filter', 'choice', array(
            'empty_data' => null,
            'empty_value' => $channelString,
            'choices' => $cha,
            'label' => false
         )
     )
     ->getForm();
```

That is how i create my form and this is how i rendered it on the twig

```
{{form_start(form, {'action':  path('business_users_page', { 'channel': form_row(form.Filter.vars.value }) }) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <label class="repsys-label">Channels:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ form_row(form.Filter, { 'attr': { 'onChange': "this.form.submit();", 'class': 'form-control'}})}} 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 div-error">
        {{msg}}
    </div>
{{ form_end(form)}}
```

I tried some answers posted in here, problem is their form is all in html with some twig and not in formbuilder.

I have tried `form.Filter.vars.value` and `form.vars.value.Filter`.

Comment: Where are you trying to access the value of the form?

Comment: Also are you looking to only use native javascript or is jquery allowed?

Comment: on the twig, cause i want the twig to pass a parameter for my url, sorry for my bad formatting, im sure, symfony can easily handle that if it is an object, or if i use html tag to make my form

Comment: So you want your form to also pass like a referrer url? I still dont quite understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: uhm yes, sorry if im to vague.

example, the value of the slect control is 3, then my url will be home/channel/3, something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try to change first line:

```
{{form_start(form, {'action':  path('business_users_page', { 'channel': form.vars.value.Filter } }) }}
```

You don't need to add **form_row** to access the field value.
Also:
    **{{ form.vars.value.Filter }}**

Documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html